# filter in a mdx query is not correctly applied

Tags: ssas, mdx

I have a MDX Filter problem, which I think I use correctly however I still get some rows which I don't want to get.
Sample query is :

```
SELECT {[Measures].[AFR],[Measures].[IB],[Measures].[IC All]} ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY ( ([dim_ProductModel].[Product Model].&[DSDB]) 
* FILTER(  ([dim_Country].[Country Name].members -[dim_Name].[Country Key].[All]),[Dim_Date].[Date Full].&[2014-01-01]*[Measures].[IB] > 0 AND NOT ISEMPTY ([Dim_Date].[Date Full].&[2014-01-01]*[Measures].[IB] )) 
* {[Dim_Date].[Date Full].&[2013-02-01]:[Dim_Date].[Date Full].&[2014-01-01]}) 
ON ROWS FROM [cub_dashboard_spares]
```

Now what I need, is to exclude those countries! (Filter) for particular product model [DSDB] in this case , where in january 2014 (dimension) the measure IB was > 0 or not null. Now it seems that it filters out correctly some countries however I still get some results, where either IB is 0 in last month OR IB is (null) in last month (January 2014 in our case).

Could please anybody help me where can be the problem?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is my problem..: don't understand why the results with AFR 0 appear :(

[image: i don't get it..]

Comment: Is `[Measures].[IB]` a calculated measure? Maybe the "non-empty behavior" setting is wrong? From Analysis Services version 2008, Microsoft suggests to leave it empty if tehre are no special reasons to use it.

Comment: hmm, but as you can see, the Measure.IB is not even used in my query, could it be a problem nevertheless?

Comment: I do not think that this setting has any influence if the measure is not used directly or indirectly (as it might be used in the calculation of another measure that is used in the query) be included in the query.

Comment: ok..so..lets say, is there any other option to filter rows where AFR = 0 and Date = 2014-01-01 after the MDX query returns all rows? as in SQL I could take my query, make it a derived query and then filter it. Could I somehow really explicitly "encapsulate" my MDX query make it a inner query and then filter this rows out? As I am not able so far to do it in one step.

Comment: i think i understand now the problem. The filter is working only as long as only the dimension is included ON ROWS which is filtered. If any other crossjoined dimensions are included, then it is not working. E.g. in my screenshot, first row (DSDB, Austria, 2014-01-10 with AFR=0) is returned, because there are other's DSDB and/or 2014-01-01 members where AFR is not 0. If I include only Country and not Product model and date, in that case the filter is correct..hmm so I need to manage somehow, that the filter is applied for the whole group, and not only one dimension. (country in my case)

Comment: I got it at least..(I hope)..you maybe have overlooked it and it is obvious for you, but, I needed to put all other dimensions (dim_ProductModel) in my case, into the filter. So that is is inside and not outside the filter as in my case was..

Answer (score 1):

I would add the country to the filter condition, i. e. use

```
SELECT {[Measures].[AFR],[Measures].[IB],[Measures].[IC All]}
       ON COLUMNS,
       NON EMPTY
       [dim_ProductModel].[Product Model].&[DSDB]
       * FILTER(([dim_Country].[Country Name].members -[dim_Name].[Country Key].[All]),
                ([dim_Country].[Country Name].CurrentMember, [Dim_Date].[Date Full].&[2014-01-01], [Measures].[IB]) > 0
                AND NOT
                ISEMPTY(([dim_Country].[Country Name].CurrentMember, [Dim_Date].[Date Full].&[2014-01-01], [Measures].[IB]))
               ) 
       * {[Dim_Date].[Date Full].&[2013-02-01]:[Dim_Date].[Date Full].&[2014-01-01]}
       ON ROWS
  FROM [cub_dashboard_spares]
```

Comment: hi Frank, unfortunately with your proposed solution I get exactly same results as with my query. I do not really understand it, maybe it helps you if I tell you, that redundant rows which I obtain via MDX query are not visible if I browse the cube via SSAS's browser. In SSAS the country members are correctly not visible.

Comment: hmm if I delete Measure.AFR then the query runs correctly. The AFR is always zero if IB is (null) or zero because it is a calculated measure from IB and IC (2 other measures)- in case of one particular country, measuru IB is 0 and measure IC and measure IB are (null). If I remove measure.AFR from SELECT part of the query, then I correctly dont get any rows back. It seems like if I involve AFR which is calculated as iif(IB>0, IC/IB, 0) then it is forced to show  all rows regardless of the filter on the IB measure.

Comment: @Peter Two remarks: 1) `NOT ISEMPTY` is not necessary if you check against `0`, see http://sqlblog.com/blogs/mosha/archive/2005/06/30/how-to-check-if-cell-is-empty-in-mdx.aspx. 2) The measure `AFR` being `0` and not `null` prevents `NON EMPTY` from suppressing these rows. This does not explain the behavior of `Filter`, however. Nevertheless, I would suggest removing the `NON EMPTY` as well as the `AND NOT ISEMPTY(...)` to make for a simpler case for testing the behavior of `Filter`.

Comment: @FrankPI thanks for your remarks, however, it is even stranger than I thought. At first I thougt NON EMPTY would not make any sense here, but without NON EMPTY I got even more (null) results sets for more countries than with NON EMPTY at the beginning. It is probably because the filter is not working entirely properly. (thoug, some results are filtered via this filter out as well)